# where condition in loopback 4 with column of other models

Tags: loopbackjs, loopback4

I have a query made through the filter on multiple models in cascade. I would like to use a column of the first level (ModelA) in the where conditions of the underlying levels, is it possible?

example:

```
const customFilter = {
    
        include:[{
            {
             relation: 'modelB',
             scope:{
                where: _this_condition_with_column_of_modelA_
             }
        }]
}
this.repository.find(customFilter) // repository on modelA
```

Comment: Are modelA and modelB related by any means ?

Comment: yes, in modelB there is foreign key for modelaA

Comment: https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Include-filter.html#include-with-filters. Try this

Comment: I would like to use a value of model A on the query of model B, beyond the link defined in the model.